# extract the Hashes property value from the Message property - Windows Event

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I extract the Hashes property value from the Message property? This is related to Windows EventID 1

Command:

```
Get-WinEvent @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational";id=1} | Select-Object -Property Message | Format-List
```

Output:

```
Message : Process Create:
          RuleName: -
          UtcTime: 2020-12-18 12:42:03.984
          ProcessGuid: {1804e376-a39b-5fdc-8c0e-000000001600}
          ProcessId: 17144
          Image: C:\Windows\System32\smartscreen.exe
          FileVersion: 10.0.19041.546 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
          Description: Windows Defender SmartScreen
          Product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
          Company: Microsoft Corporation
          OriginalFileName: smartscreen.exe
          CommandLine: C:\Windows\System32\smartscreen.exe -Embedding
          CurrentDirectory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\
          User: DESKTOP-FRCCUNT\cybersaint
          LogonGuid: {1804e376-a014-5fcb-f5ae-070000000000}
          LogonId: 0x7AEF5
          TerminalSessionId: 1
          IntegrityLevel: Medium
          **Hashes**: SHA256=1E35BB9770AE8202BD6D2E5FDA6784A80F67DCF4B547B206A14D82CC17154842
          ParentProcessGuid: {1804e376-a00f-5fcb-0c00-000000001600}
          ParentProcessId: 504
          ParentImage: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
          ParentCommandLine: C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch -p
```

Comment: I don't have sysmon installed either. Can you show us what `(Get-WinEvent @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational";id=1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Message).GetType()` returns?

Comment: IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Comment: Apologies. It did help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you say, the message comes as a string array, you could do this to extract the 'Hashes':

```
$msg = Get-WinEvent @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational";id=1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Message
$hashes = if ($msg | Where-Object { $_ -match '^Hashes\s*:\s*(\w+)=(.*)' }) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{ Algorithm = $matches[1]; Value = $matches[2] }
}
$hashes
```

The result would be an object:

```
Algorithm Value                                                           
--------- -----                                                           
SHA256    1E35BB9770AE8202BD6D2E5FDA6784A80F67DCF4B547B206A14D82CC17154842
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sysmon installed, but I'm assuming those fields are in the xml eventdata:

```
Get-WinEvent @{logname='application'} -MaxEvents 1 | 
% { [xml]$xml = $_.toxml(); $xml.event.eventdata }

Data
----
{2020-12-19T13:29:39Z, RulesEngine}
```